# MPI error from very simple example fortran code

Tags: mpi

I have compiled this code:

```
 program mpisimple
  
  implicit none
  
  integer ierr

  include 'mpif.h'

  call mpi_init(ierr)

  write(6,*) 'Hello World!'

  call mpi_finalize(ierr)

  end
```

using the command: mpif90 -o helloworld simplempi.f90

When I run with this command:

```
    $ mpiexec -np 1 ./helloworld
    Hello World!
```

it works fine as you can see.  But when I run with any other number of processors (here 4) I get the errors and I basically have to ctrl+C to kill it.

```
Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(805).....: fail failed
MPID_Init(1859)...........: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(126).......: fail failed
MPID_nem_init_ckpt(858)...: fail failed
MPIDI_CH3I_Seg_commit(427): PMI_KVS_Get returned 4
In: PMI_Abort(69777679, Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(805).....: fail failed
MPID_Init(1859)...........: channel initialization failed
MPIDI_CH3_Init(126).......: fail failed
MPID_nem_init_ckpt(858)...: fail failed
MPIDI_CH3I_Seg_commit(427): PMI_KVS_Get returned 4)
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
```

What could be the problem?  I am doing this on a Linux hpc system.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this happened. The system I am using does not require users to submit single-core jobs through the scheduler, but does require it for multi-core jobs. Once the mpiexec command was submitted through a PBS bash script, the errors went away and output was as expected.

Comment: You probably have very low resource limits set on the head node of the cluster. `ulimit -a` shows them. This is often done deliberately to deter people from overloading the head nodes with multicore jobs.